# How to simulate choosing option from select in someones website using c# and webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-select

I know how to set value in text-input.

```
document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
                .GetElementsByName("kwota1")[0].SetAttribute("value", "12");
```

And now I want to choose option from select. I can find it by name, and what next should I do?

```
document.GetElementsByTagName("select").GetElementsByName("waluta1")[0]
```

Comment: Your question needs work, not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.GetElementsByTagName("select").GetElementsByName("waluta1")[0].SetAttribute("selected", "true");
```